# Update mysql data while not actually using it

Tags: php, mysql

How can I set up a program in which a certain piece of data for a user is updated every hour. One example I can give is Mafia Wars. When you obtain property, your money is incremented every set amount of time based on which property it is. **I'm not asking to spit out code for me, but rather to guide me in the right direction for a solution.** I tried looking into cron jobs, but that only runs a script on a set time. Different users are going to be using this, and they may have different times to update their information. So thus, cron jobs are not applicable here.

Comment: Cronjob doesn't work in this exact situation.

Comment: Of course it does. You just have to be creative. It wouldn't make much sense to run a script every second or so.. Also you can't just set timeouts like in JavaScript, and forking off processes when running under a webserver is always a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that I came up with when wondering how to implement such a thing is that whenever the player saves the game, the game saves the current time. Then, when the player loads the game back up, it calculates how many minutes have passed and figures out how much money the game should give the player. Then, you could update the SQL database to reflect the changes.

Comment: this is the way to do it, IMO

Comment: This sounds reasonable! Thank you! :D

Comment: The problem is that you cannot query data across players for example for a "richest players" ranking (because not all are up-to-date).

Comment: @Thilo I was thinking more along the lines of a game with no hiscores, so I didn't even take that into consideration. Although, if there's no highscore lists my method has an advantage in that if the server goes down, the player would still earn what they would normally.

Answer (score 4):

You could still have cron jobs, just lots of them (not one per user, but maybe one per minute).

Also, Mafia Wars strikes me as not very interactive, so it may be enough to just update the data (after the fact) when the user (or some other part of the system) next looks at it. So when you log in after 37 hours, you get all the updates for the last 37 hours retroactively applied. Cheap trick, but if there is no need for a consistent global view, that might work, too.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you dismiss cron jobs? Have a cron job that runs a script in short intervals. Within this script, include logic to check which specific updates on the database have to be done.

Answer (score 0):

A cron job that runs *something* is your friend. 
What that something is, is up to you. It could be a PHP script that runs some mysql queries or procedures, or it could straight mysql command from the command line.
Either way, Cron (and other similiar tools) are exactly the bill for these tasks. It's lightweight, on nearly every server in the land, lots of help avaliable for it, and it 99.9999% of the time, it just works!